# Transformar um vetor de bytes em DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

Estou lendo um arquivo de excel (xls, xlsx, csv) e exibindo seu conteúdo em uma página nova usando DataSet. Eu consigo fazer para xls e xlsx, mas pra csv não ta rolando.

```
public static DataSet result;

public static void prepareFile(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
        Stream stream = file.InputStream;
        IExcelDataReader reader = null;
        byte[] fileDataCsv;

        if (file.FileName.EndsWith(".csv")) {
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            fileDataCsv = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
            showCsv(fileDataCsv);
        } else if (file.FileName.EndsWith(".xls")) {
            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
            showXls(reader);
        } else if (file.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx")) {
            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            showXls(reader);
        } else {
            //TODO: Message error
            return;
        }    
    }
```

Vi em alguns foruns algumas pessoas chegando bem perto do que queria usando `byte[]`, mas não consigo descobrir o que preciso fazer para transformar esses `byte[]` em `DataSet`.

Alguma ideia?

PS: Sei que posso estar fazendo errado, então fico aberto a exibir esse arquivo .csv de qualquer outra forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria de outra forma:

```
 //Declaro o StreamReader para o caminho onde se encontra o arquivo 
        StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(@"e:\file.csv"); 
        //Declaro uma string que será utilizada para receber a linha completa do arquivo 
        string linha = null; 
        //Declaro um array do tipo string que será utilizado para adicionar o conteudo da linha separado 
        string[] linhaseparada = null; 
        //realizo o while para ler o conteudo da linha 
        while ((linha = rd.ReadLine()) != null) 
        { 
            //com o split adiciono a string 'quebrada' dentro do array 
            linhaseparada = linha.Split(';'); 
            //aqui incluo o método necessário para continuar o trabalho 

        } 
        rd.Close();
```

Comment: Obrigado! Fiz algumas modificações no meu código e consegui adequar :)